# How would one identify an LED like this?

Tags: led, identification

I have a simple LED circuit from a cheap light and I'm wanting to replace it with a warmer variant. The only problem is that I cannot identify it.

Here is the board in question:

[image]

I have Google'd both the "10236" and the "JR381" and both together, but to no luck...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think anyone can identify what the LED on the circuit board is. The circuit board markings have nothing to do with what the LED is. Simply measure the LED forward voltage and current, or just use the battery voltage, and replace the LED with any LED you like and optionally change the resistor to get suitable current.

Comment: It's far better to measure chip size and specify voltage used and how warm and bright you need it.  but my guess is a 3528 metric

Comment: https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/everlight-electronics-co-ltd/EAHC2835WD1/6002460 or https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/everlight-electronics-co-ltd/EAHC2835WD3/6002461

Answer (score 2):

My assumptions from inspection are; 5V input 3.5mm x 2.8 mm  18 ohms implies if 3.1V 5-3.1=1.9V then / 18 Ohms = 105 mA for a part rated @ 150 mA means Cu PCB will get hot but not burning hot.

Warm and warmer are 4000 'K and 3000 'K available at D-K

https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/everlight-electronics-co-ltd/EAHC2835WD1/6002460

or https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/everlight-electronics-co-ltd/EAHC2835WD3/6002461

A wider range of choices

https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/filter/led-lighting-white/124?s=N4IgjCBcpgbFoDGUBmBDANgZwKYBoQB7KAbRAHZzYAWAJhAIE5qAOWegXQIAcAXKEAGVeAJwCWAOwDmIAL4EAzOQQhkkdNnxFSIOmDCMWDXbX3lqILiD4Dh46XIIBWagpVqNuAsUhlmT82MwAAZghTCg4KcWagsCfTBWYMsefkghUUkZeRAAWnpoVShRAFctHzInS1kaoA

Plan on 3 seconds per solder joint max or tack , solder , repeat

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a 2835 size which several manufactures make. The problem is, some are anode left side and some are anode right side so just make,sure you get the one you need.  Cree, Samsung have the most variety (color temps) with good CRI in this size.
2835 means, 2.8mm x 3.5mm.  Measure yours to be sure I'm right.